# Why I cannot run this process？I use three for，but it report mistake

Tags: java, math

// Title: 1,2,3,4 figures , the number of each other with no repeat of the three-digit numbers can be composed ? How many are ?

```
 public class Eleven {

     public static void main(String[] args) {

          // Definition of one hundred , ten , a bit
          // The first one hundred first statistics
         for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++) {

              // This bit is a one hundred
             int bai = i;
             for (int j = 1; j < 5 && (i != j); j++) {
                 int shi = j;
             }

              //Question1:Icannot understand it,Why it tell me mistake?a<5 &&(a !=bai &&(a !=shi)
             for (int a = 1; a < 5 && (a != bai && (a != shi)); a++) {
                 int ge = a;
             }

              //Define a three-digit number , his output
             int Threefingue = bai * 100 + shi * 10 + ge;

             System.out.print(Threefingue);
          }
     }
 }
```

Comment: When posting questions about errors, please include the *complete* error, in full and unedited. Please edit your question to include what the compiler or runtime is telling you.

Comment: `shi` is declared in the scope of the second for loop, you can not access it in the declaration of the third.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: What is purpose of your code actually? Finding all possible numbers with three unique digits??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem (I suppose since you don't mention the error you get, lies within these lines:

```
//Define the ten
         int shi=j;
         }
        //Question1:Icannot understand it,Why it tell me mistake?a<5 &&(a !=bai &&(a !=shi)
        for(int a =1;a<5 &&(a !=bai &&(a !=shi));a++)
         {
             //Define the bit
             int ge=a;
         }
```

Indeed, in the first `for` loop you declare `int shi` so you can only use it in this first for loop. However you do use it as well in the condition of your second `for` loop. You should not do that. To solve this, declare shi outside of the first `for` loop and you should not run into this problem.

Comment: Yes，I know you。I try it against.Thank you very much.